# Unable to calculate logarithm of a number error method log10 ln

Tags: rust

When I tried to get a logarithm of a number I'm getting following errors in Substrate, how to fix this?

```
  437 |         let cc = f32::log10(4 as f32);
      |                       ^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `f32`

  error[E0599]: no method named `log10` found for type `f32` in the current scope
     --> /home/dev/Desktop/projects/GIANT/pallets/provider/src/lib.rs:439:20
      |
  439 |         let x =  1.0_f32.log10() -  2.0_f32.log10();
      |                          ^^^^^ method not found in `f32`

  error[E0599]: no method named `log10` found for type `f32` in the current scope
     --> /home/dev/Desktop/projects/GIANT/pallets/provider/src/lib.rs:439:39
      |
  439 |         let x =  1.0_f32.log10() -  2.0_f32.log10();
      |                                             ^^^^^ method not found in `f32`

|         let e = ln(1.0 / 2.0);
      |                 ^^ not found in this scope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really cannot use floating point numbers in the runtime since floating point numbers are not deterministic. You can learn a lot more why with other online resources like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0).

Instead you should be looking to use the primitives provided by [`sp_arithmetic`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/index.html), which uses fixed point numbers to ensure determinism and safety in the runtime.

It does not seem there is a log10 currently implemented, but you can implement it yourself and make a PR to Substrate using a taylor series like [noted here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/logarithm-math-operation-in-solidity)